# Returning Values from Cloud Functions for Firebase to iOS app

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use the following Cloud Function for Firebase to communicate between Stripe and my iOS App. However, although `console.log(customer)` prints out a valid customer JSON object, my iOS app receives `nil` as the result. Am I returning it in the wrong way?

```
exports.regCustomer = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
    const email = data.email;

    return stripe.customers.create({
        email: email,
    }, function(err, customer) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('stripe-error', err);
        } else {
            console.log("customer successfully created");
            console.log(customer);
            return customer;
        }
    });                                               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the promise mode of the Stripe Node.js library and not the callback mode, see https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Promises

Then, modifying your code along these lines should do the trick:

```
exports.regCustomer = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const email = data.email;

    return stripe.customers.create({
        email: email
    })
    .then(function(customer) {
        console.log("customer successfully created");
        console.log(customer);
        return {customer: customer};

    }, function(err) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('stripe-error', err);
    });

});
```